# How to connect PouchDB with Ionic Framework

Tags: ionic-framework, pouchdb

I am not able to connectivity of ionic with pouchDB and SqliteDB

How to connect pouchDB with ionic framework.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Within mobile apps, it's best practise not to directly connect your phone to the database. This creates a lot more data traffic, which you don't want on a mobile device.

Best practise is creating a rest api which returns the data you want from the database to your app. Most of the time this is a php page, which you can call from within the app with a html request, and then returns the data from the database as JSON.

However, if you really want to use SQLite, you can use [sql.js](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js).